# Auto-login visitors from a specific Sharepoint Site

Tags: php, security, sharepoint, autologin

Visitors of a external Sharepoint site, will click a link and will be redirected to our site. Our site requires login, but we want the visitors from that Sharepoint site to be automatically logged in.

How safe is (or is it, at all?) to rely on HTTP_REFERER super-global in PHP? Or how should I accomplish this task?

Comment: It depends on what your page is doing - all of the headers (like HTTP_REFERER) can be spoofed, but it's not something that the average user will be doing, only a malicious one.  
If all you are doing is showing some sort of "Welcome to our Sharepoint friends" page, then there shouldn't be any harm in using the HTTP_REFERER header.  If you want more security, you'll have to get into sessions and embedding a session ID in a url.

Comment: I have little control over the SP site. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to deploy any custom code (that is developed in .NET). I can only edit the pages with SP Designer tool. Actually this is the main problem, which leads me to this Question.

Comment: I just can't think of a way this can be done (safely or not) using just SPD.

Comment: Well, the answer would be that you actually can, but you shouldn't because you provide a security hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PHP code is run on the same server/domain, you might be able to read the cookies. Otherwise, relying on REFERRER is a big security risk.

I would use Javascript to add some authentication information onto the end of the URL. Sharepoint can be a pain to add custom javascript though.